# C: wait for a signal

Tags: c, process, set

I have a problem with this code..

I need to put in wait (`sigwait`) a process until arrive almost one of those Signals `SIGUSR1`/`SIGUSR2` (maybe I can use `sigalrm` to catch the signals?)

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    sigset_t set;
    int sig;

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR2);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    sigwait(&set, &sig);
    printf("Got signal %d\n", sig);
    /*need to set Sigalrm?*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And *what* problem do you have with the shown code? Have you checked return value of e.g. `sigwait`?

Comment: It's not wait for the signal.. [ On success, sigwait() returns 0.  On error, it returns a positive error
       number (listed in ERRORS).]

Comment: use `signal` function to handle your signal!

Comment: @Sathish That's for handing a signal asynchronously, he wants to wait for the signal. That's precisely what `sigwait()` is for.

Comment: @user3121134 Is it returning an error?

Comment: You are BLOCKING those signals. You need SIG_UNBLOCK.

Comment: You can generate the signals you want at the shell with `kill -s`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: ok so I have to change sigprocmask in sig_setmask right?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: That's the way you use `sigwait`. The OP got that one right.

Comment: sigwait() does the unblocking for you.  The OP got it right, you must call `sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);` before the `sigwait()` or you have a race condition.  However you also need to define a (do nothing) signal handler for the signals as @Sathish suggested as the default action for SIGUSR1/2 to to terminate the process.  I can't see any use for SIGALRM here.